# Using && in jquery if condition under function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am checking value on radio and select drop down using jquery. How can check both elements value in a if condition using jquery ? I tried this way but its not working for me:

```
$("#filterresult").click(function(){
if($('#filter_deductible').val()=="id_0" && $('#trip_type_filter_no').val()=="no")
  {
//some code here
  }
```

I know I can't use && in jquery code I have to use multiple selector but I don't know how to use it. Any suggestions please ?

Here is my html:

```
<select id="filter_deductible" name="filter_deductible">
<option value="">Select Deductible</option>
<option value="id_0">0 Only</option>
<option value="id_0_250">0-250</option>
<option value="id_250_1000">250-1000</option>
<option value="id_1001">1000 and Higher</option>
<option value="All Deductibles">All Deductibles</option>
</select>
```

AND

```
<input type="radio" id="trip_type_filter_no" name="trip_type_filter_no" value="no" /> No
```

Calling function using a button:

```
<input type="button" name="filterresult" id="filterresult" class="newquote" value="Filter Result" />
```

Comment: But its not working for me. Its getting the first element value but not second one.

Comment: Seems right to me. Have you verified that the elements in question (like `#filter_deductible`) have the values you're expecting? Might help to show some HTML too.

Comment: jQuery is written in Javascript. So anything you can do in Javascript can be done in jQuery also.

Comment: @LeeTaylor that's not completly true but the opposite is, e.g, you cannot capture event in jQuery

Comment: I just provided my html code in the question

Comment: How are the radio buttons linked if their names are different?

Comment: Seems to work here ... http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/5s0w64dd/

Comment: Its working even you select yes radio button its should works only in case radio button having value no selected.

Comment: You aren't considering `checked` or not

Comment: Ok can you tell me how can I check if radio no checked using jquery in if condition ?

Comment: instead of $('#trip_type_filter_no').val()=="no" I can use if checked true but the problem is && not working

Comment: I think you have duplicate ID's also ...just a  guess. Please post more html for matching radio

Comment: _"I know I can't use && in jquery code I have to use multiple selector"_ Rubbish. This is still JavaScript, dude!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First radio buttons that should be linked should have the SAME name, you have different names. That means you can select both of them.

Second, the val() will always return the value. You want to check to see if it is selected.

```
if ($('#filter_deductible').val()=="id_0" && $('#trip_type_filter_no').is(":checked"))
```